# How to get a value inside an object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, key-value

I am new to javascript i have a basic question. Until now i can't face this type of object i need to reach inside {exif} inside exif object. Here is my image object

```
console.log(image);
```

When want to view image array details, below you can see the result

```
{exif: {…}, localIdentifier: "CC95F08C-88C3-4012-9D6D-64A413D254B3/L0/001", filename: "IMG_0006.HEIC", width: 4032, modificationDate: "1605251810", …}
creationDate: "1522437259"
cropRect: null
data: null
duration: null
exif:
ColorModel: "RGB"
DPIHeight: 72
DPIWidth: 72
Depth: 8
Orientation: 3
PixelHeight: 3024
PixelWidth: 4032
PrimaryImage: true
ProfileName: "Display P3"
{ExifAux}: {Regions: {…}}
{Exif}:
  ApertureValue: 2.5260688216892597
  BrightnessValue: 8.455294117647059
  ColorSpace: 65535
  ComponentsConfiguration: (4) [1, 2, 3, 0]
  CustomRendered: 2
  DateTimeDigitized: "2018:03:30 12:14:19"
  DateTimeOriginal: "2018:03:30 12:14:19"
  ExifVersion: (3) [2, 2, 1]
  ExposureBiasValue: 0
  ExposureMode: 0
  ExposureProgram: 2
  ExposureTime: 0.004784688995215311
  FNumber: 2.4
  Flash: 16
  FlashPixVersion: (2) [1, 0]
  FocalLenIn35mmFilm: 52
  FocalLength: 6
  ISOSpeedRatings: [16]
  LensMake: "Apple"
  LensModel: "iPhone X back dual camera 6mm 
  f/2.4"
  LensSpecification: (4) [4, 6, 
  1.7999999523162842, 2.4000000953674316]
  MeteringMode: 5
  PixelXDimension: 4032
  PixelYDimension: 3024
  SceneCaptureType: 0
  SceneType: 1
  SensingMethod: 2
  ShutterSpeedValue: 7.704253214638971
  SubjectArea: (4) [2007, 1503, 2209, 1327]
  SubsecTimeDigitized: "365"
  SubsecTimeOriginal: "365"
  WhiteBalance: 0
  __proto__: Object
{GPS}: {ImgDirection: 62.766961651917406, LatitudeRef: "N", HPositioningError: 6.00090661831369, DestBearingRef: "M", Latitude: 37.76007833333333, …}
{MakerApple}: {1: 10, 2: null, 3: {…}, 4: 1, 5: 173, 6: 170, 7: 1, 8: Array(3), 10: 2, 12: Array(2), 13: 25, 14: 4, 16: 1, 20: 3, 23: 2048, 25: 34, 26: "q825s", 29: 0.004999999888241291, 31: 1, 32: "C55AB7A6-34BC-48FC-9F8C-9CCF675F4C62", 33: 0}
{TIFF}: {TileLength: 512, Software: "12.0", ResolutionUnit: 2, DateTime: "2018:03:30 12:14:19", XResolution: 72, …}
__proto__: Object
filename: "IMG_0006.HEIC"
height: 3024
localIdentifier: "CC95F08C-88C3-4012-9D6D-64A413D254B3/L0/001"
mime: "image/jpeg"
modificationDate: "1605251810"
path: "/Users/onurcicek/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/64FBD299-2DE2-41C1-903F-53D761CDA4D3/data/Containers/Data/Application/D5250764-2878-4774-A1B8-FC965584097B/tmp/react-native-image-crop-picker/75D83B05-BF42-4786-89F0-AC7B1D103F42.jpg"
size: 4075105
sourceURL: "file:///Users/onurcicek/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/64FBD299-2DE2-41C1-903F-53D761CDA4D3/data/Media/DCIM/100APPLE/IMG_0006.HEIC"
width: 4032
__proto__: Object
```

what i want to do is reach {exif}'s values
for example

```
  console.log(image.exif.{exif}.LensMake);
```

But i always get undefined please help

Comment: The console text dump that you've posted is corrupt (we can't tell what properties belong to what objects). Please post a screenshot of the console dump.

Answer (score 0):

You can use bracket `[]` notation for this. example:
 `console.log(image.exif['{exif}']LensMake);`